# Using the Ollydbg,anyone tell me what the address of the variable "a" is?

Tags: c, reverse-engineering, decompiling, ollydbg

My very simple tested program

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int a = 12345;
printf("%d\n", a);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;

}
```

After compiled and connected,the EXE file is created.Then I open the EXE file in the Ollydbg:
[image: OllyDbg]

The picture shows the main() function.But I can't find out what the address of the variable `a` is. When passing the params to the  `printf()` function,it push `3039` into the stack, then it means the value of the variable `a` is `3039`? No,the value is `12345`. So it means the address of the variable `a` is `00003039`? Anyone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Address of the `a` variable is `[ebp-8]`. You are seeing `0x3039` assignment, because decimal `12345` is hexadecimal `0x3039`. If you change your code to use hex value: `int a = 0x12345`, results would be more clear:
[image: IDA results]

Numeric constants are usually compiled directly into the code.

Comment: thank you .I have not realize (12345)10 = (0x3039)16

Answer (score 0):

so you want to know the address of the variable `a`.

Extremely simple:

insert this statement into your program.

```
printf( "address of variable 'a' is: %p\n", &a );
```

How are we to know the address?

We are not sitting at your computer

and it will be different on most every computer.

Use the suggested call to `printf()` to learn the 'address'

HOWEVER, due to paging, address translation, virtual addressing, etc.  That address is NOT the actual physical address within your computers' memory space.

Answer (score 0):

local variables like in this case, a, are stored in the stack, so they can be discarded when a function execution is finished, so basically a is simply located at the memory address of the local stack frame.

```
int a = 12345; // MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-8], 3039
printf("%d\n", a);
```

in this case, a is located in [EBP-8], if you inspect where it is pointing, you can see the value 3039, stored in there of course after the assignment, 3039 is a hex number, which of course 12345 in base 10.

Answer (score 0):

To get better understanding of this, let's modify the program a little bit and debug it in GDB.

```
C:\Codes>gdb test -q
Reading symbols from C:\Codes\test.exe...done.
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb) list
1       #include<stdio.h>
2
3       int main()
4       {
5         int a = 12345;
6         int b = 0x12345;
7         printf("Variable a %d (decimal) or  0x%x (hex), located at %p or 0x%x\n", a,a,&a,&a);
8         printf("Variable b %d (decimal) or 0x%x (hex), located at %p or 0x%x\n", b,b,&b,&b);
9         return 0;
10      }
(gdb)
```

Standard Output

```
C:\Codes>test
Variable a 12345 (decimal) or  0x3039 (hex), located at 0022FF4C or 0x22ff4c
Variable b 74565 (decimal) or 0x12345 (hex), located at 0022FF48 or 0x22ff48
```

As you can see, the virtual memory addresses of variable `a` and `b` is actually located at `0x22ff4c` and `0x22ff48` respectively.

Let's take a look at this program in GDB.

```
(gdb) break 7
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40135e: file test.c, line 7.
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Codes/test.exe
[New Thread 3680.0xed8]

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.c:7
7         printf("Variable a %d (decimal) or  0x%x (hex), located at %p or 0x%x\n", a,a,&a,&a);
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00401340 <+0>:     push   ebp
   0x00401341 <+1>:     mov    ebp,esp
   0x00401343 <+3>:     and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x00401346 <+6>:     sub    esp,0x30
   0x00401349 <+9>:     call   0x401970 <__main>
   0x0040134e <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x2c],0x3039
   0x00401356 <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x28],0x12345
=> 0x0040135e <+30>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x2c]
   0x00401362 <+34>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x2c]
   0x00401366 <+38>:    lea    ecx,[esp+0x2c]
   0x0040136a <+42>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x10],ecx
   0x0040136e <+46>:    lea    ecx,[esp+0x2c]
   0x00401372 <+50>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],ecx
   0x00401376 <+54>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],edx
   0x0040137a <+58>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
   0x0040137e <+62>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403024
   0x00401385 <+69>:    call   0x401be0 <printf>
   0x0040138a <+74>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [esp+0x28]
   0x0040138e <+78>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x28]
   0x00401392 <+82>:    lea    ecx,[esp+0x28]
   0x00401396 <+86>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x10],ecx
   0x0040139a <+90>:    lea    ecx,[esp+0x28]
   0x0040139e <+94>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],ecx
   0x004013a2 <+98>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],edx
   0x004013a6 <+102>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],eax
   0x004013aa <+106>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x403064
   0x004013b1 <+113>:   call   0x401be0 <printf>
   0x004013b6 <+118>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x004013bb <+123>:   leave
   0x004013bc <+124>:   ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

And focus on this line

```
   0x0040134e <+14>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x2c],0x3039
   0x00401356 <+22>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x28],0x12345
```

As you can see from the previous output, the virtual memory address of variables `a` and `b` is actually located at `[esp+0x2c]` or `0x22ff4c` and `[esp+0x28]` or `0x22ff48` respectively.

while

`0x3039` & `0x12345` are the value of variables `a` and `b` in hexadecimal.

To verify the memory address of these variables in GDB, use `print` command as follows:

```
(gdb) print &a
$1 = (int *) 0x22ff4c

(gdb) print &b
$2 = (int *) 0x22ff48
```

Also, you might wonder where the address of `0x22ff4c` or `0x22ff48` come from.

To understand this, let's check the value of current ESP register

```
(gdb) info registers esp
esp            0x22ff20 0x22ff20
```

Then, replace the actual ESP value

```
[esp+0x2c] = [0x22ff20 + 0x2c] = 0x22ff4c
[esp+0x28] = [0x22ff20 + 0x28] = 0x22ff48
```